# Issue using MFMessageComposeViewController on iPhone 8 and iPhone 8 plus running iOS11

Tags: ios, iphone, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

iPhone 8 and iPhone 8 plus using iOS 11 are not able to open MFMessageComposeViewController from inside the iOS Application. They sometimes open a black screen.

Is anyone else facing this issue on iPhone 8 running iOS 11 and has found a solution? Please help.

I manage to reproduce this issue only on iPhone 8 running iOS 11.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it's a bug with iOS 11.

Comment: Have you fixed this problem??

Comment: Any fix? My users are experiencing the same. I dont have an iPhone 8 to test it.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem on ios 11? Any fix on this?

Answer (score -1):

try to set MFMessageComposeViewController.subject with a not null value.